# How to create a chrome texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Is it possible to get that typical chrome-like *angled look* using the *Shader Editor*? I see a lot of tutorials making chrome on all types of surfaces but not on a knob geometry like the one in the following image:

[image]

**Q:** Is there any way to get that chrome-like surface appearance procedurally or should I just use a texture to fake it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy peasy...that's just Anisotropic glossiness.  Just set Anisotropic to 1.0, and then play with the Roughness value to get the look you want.  No tutorial needed!

[image]

EDIT:

Use a Tangent node to control the axis of the anisotropy:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dale, thanks for your reply. Yours looks way cooler, than what I tried to do.
I'm copying your settings, but I'm not getting any angles. just a straight line. What am I doing wrong?

(I also changed the render to cycles)

https://ibb.co/mhTdsCw

Comment: Did you UV-Unwrap it? That might be necessary, if I remember correctly..

Comment: hmm, maybe it has to do with the rotation or how you modeled the cylinder?  you could try plugging in a Tangent node and see if trying X, Y, or Z gives you the results you want (see the image I added above)

Comment: you don't need to UV Unwrap or anything. I'm not using Blender 2.8x but I would hope they didn't change the behavior of something so simple.

Comment: The axis is in object space, and defaults to Z if nothing is plugged in.

Comment: It worked well using your settings. 

Kind regards.

Comment: if that's the case then can you please mark my answer as "correct"?  thanks!

Comment: @blenderbreath Hey, accept the guy's answer, please. Or the other guy's if that's your preference.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using EEVEE, you'll have to fake it.

One way:

[image]

.. The 'Tangent' axis is down the axis of the cylinder, in the object's space.

Comment: Using EEVEE certainly does speed up times within an instance, so your solution was on point.

Thank you for your reply.