# Custom anisotropic material not quite working as expected

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

Working in Blender 2.82a, I have noted that the Anisotropic does not work in eevee, so I try to create my own. I managed to make it half work, but I may have misunderstood a node value.

[image: 23mb animation]

If you follow the pink "scar" you will see that it shifts as I move the view, but when I move the light the "scar" does not shift. The Shader setup is as follows.

[image: Shader Node Setup to try and simulate an Anisotropic Shader]

I am guessing `Incoming` is not the node I should use if I want the "scar" to react to the lights. What should I use instead?

Comment: Hello :). @RobinBetts to the rescue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168190/

Comment: Perfect! And figured out the maths to have it shift when shifting the UV. Thanks!