# Why can't I find an anisotropic BSDF in the list of Shader nodes when I've used it before

Tags: shader-nodes

I followed a tutorial for hair that used a anisotropic BSDF, but when I went to recreate the setup for hair for another model I no longer had an anisotropic BSDF listed. Is there any way I can copy/ import the  one from the 1st model or is there another node I can use instead to put between the bump and the mix shader. Does disappearing nodes mean I should uninstall and reinstall my version of blender.

Comment: Most likely, it's because the render engine is set to Eevee. Change it to Cycles.

Comment: As lemon says, _Anisotropic BSDF_ is only available in Cycles, not Eevee. So no need for re-installing Blender. But I don't know if there is any substitute you could use under Eevee.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/168180/ (about faking anisotropy in Eevee)

Comment: [Fake Anisotropic in EEVEE](http://jeromebelleman.gitlab.io/posts/graphics/anisotropy/) in case you want a simple EEVEE setup