# Anisotropic textures from Substance Painter to Blender

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm trying to export anisotropic materials. Seems all fine until I load them into Blender and I cannot see the anisotropic texture on my object. I was told to add emissive to the channels to see if it worked but it didn't when I added the textures to my object in blender.

I'm hoping someone can tell me how its possible, because the Adobe forum, no one has replied.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the Anisotropy Level and Angle as new output maps.

(Anisotropy Angle -> RGB)
(Anisotropy Level -> Grayscale)

[image: Substance Painter Export Settings]

Then use those output maps to feed into the Anisotropy and rotation in blender. You may want to add a 'Tangent' node to adjust the radial effect.

You can also use the Anisotropic shader, which I think gives slightly better Aniso lighting effects, but isn't as flexible as Principled:
[image]
(Anisotropic BSDF left, Principled BSDF right)
[image]

Comment: Could this also be applied for EEVEE render engine?

Comment: I don't think EEVEE supports the anisotropic shader.  However you could create an export map for the '2D view' and use that to fake it.  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Hi @blenderbreath :). Robin Betts will probably know  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168190/78972

Comment: Hi Jeff, which Alpha is this?

https://postimg.cc/3kVvMjPq

Comment: @blenderbreath came from the standard blender BSDF, I think it was Opacity (GrayScale) doesn't really do anything! Swapped image with the key.